# If and else statement at the same time though it shouldn't be possible

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

I'm experiencing a very weird problem in eclipse.
Look at the following code:

```
public void addItem(ArrayList<Object> objectLists)  {

        SHorizontalLayout hLayout = Cf.hLayout();
        hLayout.setSizeFull();
        hLayout.setHeight(rowHeight, UNITS_PIXELS);
        if(rowCount % 2 != 0 && rowCount != 0)  {
            hLayout.addStyleName("row-even");
        } else  {
            hLayout.addStyleName("row-odd");            
        }

        for(Object object : objectLists)    {

            if(object instanceof String || object instanceof Integer)   {
                hLayout.addComponent(Cf.h1(object.toString()), Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
                columnList.get(0).addComponent(hLayout);                
            } else if(object instanceof ChipSlotGrid)   {
                hLayout.addComponent((ChipSlotGrid)object, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
                columnList.get(1).addComponent(hLayout);            
            }
        }

        rowCount++;
    }
```

In the for loop the object is checked for instance type and added accordingly into a layout.

The problem I'm experiencing though is that when the object is of type `Integer` it enters the *if statement*, executes the two rows inside the statement, and then instead of leaving for a new cycle in the loop it jumps into the else statement, executing row `columnList.get(1).addComponent(hLayout)` (skipping the first row in the else statement).

It's executing parts of the else statement too even though it has already entered the if statement.I know this because I see the product of it in the application I'm developing and I've seen it programmatically when I'm debugging the code.

If I'm to break down the problem into the smallest components:

```
i = 0;    
if(true)   {
   i++;
} else   {
   i++;
}

System.out.println(i);
```

With my problem the printout would be: 2

I'm at a loss here. Is there something wrong with my IDE? Has anyone encountered this before and have any idea of what could be wrong?

**EDIT:** 
I've tried switching the statements around and can conclude that the pattern repeats itself.

```
for(Object object : objectLists)    {

        if(object instanceof ChipSlotGrid)  {
            hLayout.addComponent((ChipSlotGrid)object, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
            columnList.get(1).addComponent(hLayout);                
        } else if(object instanceof String || object instanceof Integer)    {
                hLayout.addComponent(Cf.h1(object.toString()), Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
                columnList.get(0).addComponent(hLayout);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2:** From Jon's request I added logging to the statements.

```
for(Object object : objectLists)    {

            if(object instanceof ChipSlotGrid)  {
                log.info("Inside if");
                hLayout.addComponent((ChipSlotGrid)object, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
                columnList.get(1).addComponent(hLayout);
            } else if(object instanceof String || object instanceof Integer)    {
                    log.info("Inside else");
                    hLayout.addComponent(Cf.h1(object.toString()), Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
                    columnList.get(0).addComponent(hLayout);
            }
        }
```

When it jumps from the if statement to the else statement the log in the else statement is also skipped. (I hope this was the test you requested)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild your application?

Comment: I strongly suspect you're running an out-of-date build or something similar. I very much doubt that this is *really* happening - Java doesn't just "skip" statements.

Comment: @AlexisPigeon I've now cleaned and rebuilt the application (a bit embarrassed I didn't do that before). But the problem persists.

Comment: @AndroidHustle Then you might want to check the answers already given: make sure you are running the code you actually see, and force a rebuild by actually changing the faulty condition.

Comment: @JonSkeet I would agree with you but the build is up to date and the problem persists. I've restarted Eclipse, cleaned and rebuilt the application and it still enters both statements. I realize how stupid it sounds, and I know there is some problem with the project at my end, but nonetheless it's there.

Comment: What happens if you add logging before each of the lines within the if and the else? Can you reproduce this every time? Can you reduce it to a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet I added an edit. The problem is consistent if that was your question. I don't think I could easily reduce it to a short program, the columnList consists of a non standard java type, but a type from a web application framework, and I therefore see problems with reducing it.

Comment: Maybe the `object` is not `ChipSlotGrid` nor `String` neither `Integer`, try adding an `else` to the last `if` and log "another class" message.

Comment: Can you restart Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

If your code looks like this:

```
if(object instanceof String || object instanceof Integer)   {
    hLayout.addComponent(Cf.h1(object.toString()), Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    columnList.get(0).addComponent(hLayout);                
} else if(object instanceof ChipSlotGrid)   
    hLayout.addComponent((ChipSlotGrid)object, Alignment.MIDDLE_CENTER);
    columnList.get(1).addComponent(hLayout);
```

(note the lack of curly brackets on the `else if`) then only the first line will be considered subject to the condition, and the second line will always be evaluated.

That's the only thing I can think of that would cause what you're explaining. Are you sure that the code you're looking at in your IDE is exactly what's being executed? If you have a class with the same package and name in more than one JAR, for example, then it may be using an outdated version of the class.

Comment: Unless I'm looking at an older edit, I see curly braces around the last `else if`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good guess but the statements have correct syntax and are properly encapsulated in curly brackets.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this behavior with Eclipse Indigo. It seems to be a problem with the Eclipse not being in sync with your source code. "Clean" did not resolve the issue for me. To fix it, I merely  changed the conditions of the if statement, rebuilt, debugged and then changed my if statement back to the way it was **without using undo**.

Comment: I will +1 this post if you add hot plug into the equation. Sometimes that can be the case as well.

Comment: By "hot plug" do you mean new Eclipse plugins without restarting?

Comment: Sorry, come from a C# background. Is it called HotSwap here? Basically, you can edit the code while it is running and JVM is supposed to execute the new code.

Comment: Oh yeah, this problem exists even without "realtime editing." In fact, editing the code while your debugging might actually circumvent this issue. Based on the OP, I don't think he is actually debugging, but just seeing the bad results. I'm pretty sure it is the Eclipse compiler.

Answer (score 0):

`addItem` creates a single `SHorizontalLayout` then the loop adds components to it and adds that same layout object to possibly more than one container in `columnList`.  Are you sure that's what you want?

For instance, with the code as written above, if the `objectLists` parameter contains an `Integer` and a `ChipSlotGrid` in that order, the method will create an `SHorizontalLayout`, add the `Integer`'s component to it, add the layout object to column 0, add the `ChipSlotGrid`'s component to the layout, then add the same layout object to column 1.

If this is anything like other layout frameworks I've used, when you add the layout object to the column 1 container, it will be removed from the column 0 container, but will still contain both the `Integer` component and `ChipSlotGrid` components added earlier, which might perhaps look like both branches of the `if` statement were executed.

There isn't enough code provided to see for me to tell whether this is actually causing the problem you're experiencing, but I suspect it might be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely the function is `addItem()` itself is getting called twice. I notice `rowCount` itself is defined outside of `addItem`.
If you increment a variable outside the for loop, call it `int callCount` or something and do `callCount++` before the for loop.

I bet that it will get incremented to 2, because `addItem` is getting called 2 times